# How to change tags with lxml in Python?

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I want to change all tags names `<p>` to `<para>` using lxml in python.

Here's an example of what the xml file looks like.

```
<concept id="id15CDB0Q0Q4G"><title id="id15CDB0R0VHA">General</title>
<conbody><p>This section</p></conbody>
<concept id="id156F7H00GIE"><title id="id15CDB0R0V1W">
System</title>
<conbody><p> </p>
<p>The 
</p>
<p>status.</p>
<p>sensors.</p>
```

And I've been trying to code it like this but it doesn't find the tags with .findall.

```
from lxml import etree
doc = etree.parse("73-20.xml")
print("\n")

print(etree.tostring(doc, pretty_print=True, xml_declaration=True, encoding="utf-8"))
print("\n")

raiz = doc.getroot()
print(raiz.tag)
children = raiz.getchildren()
print(children)
print("\n")

libros = doc.findall("p")
print(libros)
print("\n")

for i in range(len(libros)):
    if libros[i].find("p").tag == "p" :
        libros[i].find("p").tag = "para"
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Your sample XML is invalid (lacks closing tags).

Comment: start by uploading a VALID xml. Explain what do you try to do and what is wrong.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68415303/how-to-change-different-hierarchy-tags-in-python-with-lxml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lxml `findall()` function provides ability to search by path:

```
libros = raiz.findall(".//p")

for el in libros:
    el.tag = "para"
```

Here `.//p` means that lxml will search nested `p` elements as well.