# How to change different hierarchy tags with lxml?

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I want to change all tags names `<p>` to `<PARAGRAPH>` using lxml in python. The problem is I'm able to change the outer concept tag's `<p>` tag and the first inner concept `<p>` tag, but I don't know how to change all the remaining `<p>` tags.

Here's an example of what the xml file looks like.

```xml
<dita>
    <topic id="id15CDB0PL09E">
        <title id="id15CDB0R0VYB"><?FM MARKER [Header/Footer $1] All?>Control
        </title>
        <shortdesc>CONTROL</shortdesc>
        <concept id="id15CDB0Q0Q4G">
            <title id="id15CDB0R0VHA">General
            </title>
            <conbody>
                <p>This section
                </p>
            </conbody>
            <concept id="id156F7H00GIE">
                <title id="id15CDB0R0V1W">System
                </title>
                <conbody>
                    <p>Engine  
                    </p>
                    <p>The ECU 
                    </p>
                    <p>The aircraft 
                    </p>
                    <p>The system
                    </p>
               </conbody>
            </concept>
        </concept>
    </topic>
</dita>
```

Here's my python code using lxml.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Spyder Editor

This is a temporary script file.
"""

from lxml import etree
doc = etree.parse("73-20.xml")

#Lista para guardar las tag que son hijas de la tag concept
conceptDentro=[]
conbodysFuera=[]
conbodysDentro=[]

#Consigue la root tag (en este caso es dita y su unico hijo es topic)
raiz = doc.getroot()
print(raiz.tag)
print("\n")

#Encuentra todos los tag concept que son hijos de la tag topic
conceptAfuera = raiz[0].findall("concept")
print(conceptAfuera)
print("\n")


#Con este ciclo encuentra las tag concept que son hijas de la tags conceptAfuera
for i in range(len(conceptAfuera)):
    #conbodysFuera son los tag conbody que son hijos de los conceptAfuera, en este caso solo hay 1
    conbodysFuera.extend(conceptAfuera[i].findall("conbody"))
    #conceptDentro son las tags concept dentro de las tag conceptAfuera
    conceptDentro.extend(conceptAfuera[i].findall("concept"))

#ConceptDentro es una lista que almacena todas las tag concept dentro de las tag conceptAfuera    
print("Etiquetas de conceptDentro: ",conceptDentro) 
print("\n")
print("Etiquetas de conbodysFuera: ",conbodysFuera)
print("\n")

#Ciclo para encontrar todas las tag conbody dentro de los conceptDentro
for i in range(len(conceptDentro)):
    conbodysDentro.extend(conceptDentro[i].findall("conbody"))

print("Etiquetas de conbodysDentro: ", conbodysDentro)
print("\n")

#Ciclo para cambiar la tag p de conbodysFuera
for i in range(len(conbodysFuera)):
    for j in range(len(conbodysFuera[i].findall("p"))):
        conbodysFuera[i].findall("p")[j].tag="PARAGRAPH"
        
#Ciclo para cambiar la tag p de conbodysDentro
for i in range(len(conbodysDentro)):
    #for j in range(len(conbodysDentro[i].findall("p"))):
        conbodysDentro[i].findall("p")[j].tag="PARAGRAPH"

#print(etree.tostring(doc, pretty_print=True, xml_declaration=True, encoding="utf-8"))
doc.write("FerNewtags.xml")
```

As you can see, the last for Ciclo is written as a comment because it causes an `IndexError: list index out of range`.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're overcomplicating it. Just find all of the `p` elements (with `.xpath()` or `.findall()`) and change the value of the .tag property...

```py
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse("73-20.xml")

for p in tree.findall(".//p"):
    p.tag = "paragraph"

tree.write("FerNewtags.xml")
```

**Output** (FerNewtags.xml)

```xml
<dita>
    <topic id="id15CDB0PL09E">
        <title id="id15CDB0R0VYB"><?FM MARKER [Header/Footer $1] All?>Control
        </title>
        <shortdesc>CONTROL</shortdesc>
        <concept id="id15CDB0Q0Q4G">
            <title id="id15CDB0R0VHA">General
            </title>
            <conbody>
                <paragraph>This section
                </paragraph>
            </conbody>
            <concept id="id156F7H00GIE">
                <title id="id15CDB0R0V1W">System
                </title>
                <conbody>
                    <paragraph>Engine
                    </paragraph>
                    <paragraph>The ECU
                    </paragraph>
                    <paragraph>The aircraft
                    </paragraph>
                    <paragraph>The system
                    </paragraph>
               </conbody>
            </concept>
        </concept>
    </topic>
</dita>
```

Comment: Thank you Daniel, in fact, I was over complicating it. This answer my question, but what if I just want to change some <p> tags depending on the text? (i.e. <p>This section</p>, and, <p>The ECU</p>) ?

Comment: @AlbertoValdivia - I'm sure you could update the xpath to check the text, but how you would actually do that would depend on what you needed to check in the text. For example, if you wanted to check for "This section" and "The ECU" specifically, you could use something like this: `tree.xpath(".//p[normalize-space()='This section' or normalize-space()='The ECU']")`